# searchDisplay controller partial matches from SQLiteDatabase

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I am new to iOS application Development. I have no prior experience using sqlite3.h or sql in general. I have implemented a UITableView displaying contacts with name and mobile number. The data is being accessed from an sqlite table. My sqlite database (MyContacts.db) is created with id, name, mobileNumber,emailID.

Now I want to implement searchDisplayController so that when the user types in a searchText, it will search for matching emailID or name and display them. I wanted to know if there is any method or sql queries I can use to check for partial matches of the searchText and search through both the columns(emailID and name). I tried using rlike but it throws error. I want to make methods/functions in which if I pass the search Text as parameter it should return a NSMutableArray of all the matching/partially matching  locations id's of sqlite database.

Comment: you can use the sql query with "like"

Answer (score 0):

You can write a sql query.

```
@"select * from Employee where EmployeeName LIKE '%%%@%%'"
```

Comment: can I use two testing criteria's like @"select * from Employee where EmployeeName LIKE '%%%@%%' or EmployeeID like CE" ?? I want the result union of two conditions